# propositional calculus problem, how to prove this right or wrong?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$A$$\rightarrow$$(B$ $\vee$ $C$ ) , $B$ $\rightarrow$ $C$ $\vDash$ $A$ $\rightarrow$ $D$

I think it's wrong but I have no idea how to prove.

Comment: I'll bet that the final letter is supposed to be "C" instead of "D". In that case the claim is true. You might want to check with the source to see if this was a typo.

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked it and it's "D" @JohnHughes

Comment: OK. It's wrong. The assignment $T, T, T, F$ to $A,B,C,D$ respectively shows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is provable that $A \to ( B \vee C ) ~,~ B \to C ~\vDash~ A \to \color{red}C$

> $$\begin{array}{|l|l:l|}\hline 1 & A\to (B\vee C) & \textsf{Premise} \\ 2 & B\to C  & \textsf{Premise} \\ \hdashline 3 & \quad \neg C & \textsf{Assume} \\ 4 & \quad \neg B & 2,3,\to\textsf{Elim (MP)} \\ 5 & \quad \neg(B\vee C) & 3,4,\wedge\textsf{Intro},\textsf{deMorgan's} \\ 6 & \quad \neg A & 1,5,\to\textsf{Elim (MP)} \\ \hline 7 & A\to C & 3,6,\to\textsf{Intro} \\ \hline \end{array}$$

However, those premises do not entail $A\to D$.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but really it's $A$ $\rightarrow$ $D$ . by the truth table, when A=true,B=true,C=true,D=false, left-hand is true but right-hand is false. then this one is false. (a counter example) is this right solution?

Answer (score 0):

$A\implies D$ is false when $A$ is true and $D$ false. The other implications will be true when $C$ be true.