# propositional calculus problem, is this right proof?

Tags: propositional-calculus

[image]

I would like to confirm my proof.

Comment: You already wrote [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727351/propositional-calculus-proof) and [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727293/propositional-calculus-problem-how-to-prove-this-right-or-wrong) and this is duplicate of them.

Comment: This is a valid proof. However, for future reference, you have the option of editing your post in (1) from choco's link above and including your attempt, or posting it as an answer in link (2) and closing the question.

Comment: ok I've got it. sorry for my bad !

Comment: Another way to verify these arguments is to also draw up a truth table. If the conclusion (A -> D V C) is true *every time* the premises (A -> B V C) (B -> D) are true, then the statement works.

However: 
If there is anywhere where a premise(s) can be false and the conclusion true, then the argument is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{}
(1)&A\implies(B\lor C)&\text{premise}\\
(2)&B\implies D&\text{premise}\\
(3)&\neg(D\lor C)&\text{assumption}\\
(4)&\neg D\land \neg C&\text{De Morgan's laws, from (3)}\\
(5)&\neg D&\text{directly form (4)}\\
(6)&\neg C&\text{directly form (4)}\\
(7)&\neg B&\text{modus tollens, from (2) and (5)}\\
(8)&\neg B \land \neg C&\text{combining (6) and (7)}\\
(9)&\neg (B \lor C)&\text{De Morgan's laws, from (8)}\\
(10)&\neg A&\text{modus tollens, from (1) and (9)}\\
(11)&\neg (D\lor C)\implies\neg A&\text{combining (3) and (10)}\\
(12)&A\implies D\lor C&\text{modus tollens, from (11)}\\
\blacksquare
\end{array}$$

Comment: really I do love you XD

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I always confuse them.